# iPhone 6 doesn't load css correctly

Tags: php, css, symfony, mobile-safari, assets

I have an application running on Symfony 3.4 and using assetic bundle for managing css/js. (I know better is to use [Webpack Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html), but I don't think it could be a problem)

The problem is that iPhone 6 (iOS 9) doesn't load css styles as expected. Other devices (Samsung, Desktop PC) and even iPhone 8 loads everything correctly.

I tried to look for errors in console in Web Inspector (iphone connected to the chrome devtools), but it didn't help me to discover the problem. The only thing I noticed, that in the 'Network' section near css file request row it shows 0 bytes in Size column and in Time column - Pending. However, clicking on it and then switching to the Preview/Response it shows the entire css file where everything exists and could be used for styling the web.

One more weird thing, is that Bootstrap styles are working. And some other styles also.

More details what do I have:

Meta tags:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Example of using css in the Twig file:

```
{% stylesheets filter="scssphp" output="css/app.css"
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/style.scss'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/font-awesome.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/select2.min.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Formatter I use:

```
Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed
```

styles.scss looks like (those imported files are in scss format):

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=GoogleFont');
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "variables";
@import "main";
@import "menu";
```

I really don't know what to do, I tried to find some information in the Google, but unfortunately without success. So, I hope to find a solution here. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will have the same problem:

The problem was in selected formatter - **Compressed**. I don't know why, but I reported the issue in their github repo: (https://github.com/leafo/scssphp/issues/589)

If you use Symfony (<= 3.4) together with this library, you can change filter in your config.yml file to Compact for example:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        scssphp:
            formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compact'
```